# enabling local and LDAP configuration for OTRS

Tags: authentication, ldap, logfile, otrs

Dears,
please be informed that I have a problem with connecting LDAP and local user connection with OTRS.

I have tried to add

```
$Self->{'AuthModule2'} = 'Kernel::System::Auth::DB';
$Self->{'AuthModule::DB::CryptType2'} = 'crypt';
```

but no success. when I added these lines and the following error appears on the web page.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

What I need to look or change in order to set it up to be functional?

Best regards,
Predrag Skundric

Comment: What's in the server error log?

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.